# Not able to use setFillColor method on display objects within a table

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So I have a collection of display objects in a table, inserted like so (some excess code was taken out):

```
for i=1,blockCount do
    local block=display.newRect(xcoord,ycoord,blockwidth,blockheight);
    local color=blocks[i];
    if(color=="red") then
        block:setFillColor(1,0,0);
        block.collision = redHit;
        block:addEventListener( "collision",block);
    elseif(color=="blue") then
        block:setFillColor(0,0,1);
        block.collision = blueHit;
        block:addEventListener( "collision",block);
        block.hp=0;
    elseif(color=="yellow") then
        block:setFillColor(1,1,0);
        block.collision = yellowHit;
        block:addEventListener( "collision",block);
    else
    end
    block.blockColor=color;
    grid[i]=block;
end
```

So grid is just a table full of rectangle objects with different properties. However, in a different spot in the code, I am trying to do this:

```
for i=1,blockCount do
    if (grid[i]~=nil) then
        local color=grid[i].blockColor;
        if (color=="blue") then
            grid[i]:setFillColor(1,0,0);
            grid[i].collision = redHit;
            grid[i].blockColor="red";
        elseif (color=="red") then
            grid[i]:setFillColor(0,0,1);
            grid[i].collision = blueHit;
            grid[i].blockColor="blue";
            grid[i].hp=0;
        end
    end
end
```

In other words, at this spot in the code, I am trying to make all red blocks blue and all blue blocks red. But it's throwing an error that it's unable to change the fill color (saying it's a nil value). Because it is getting there, it is pulling the information from the object by seeing its color, so it is not unable to access properties and functions of the object, and if I comment out that line, changing the other properties works. Why would it not be able to run this simple function?

Answer (score 0):

It means that yours grid table contains not only block elements. So one of elements stored in grid table contains no ".blockColor".
Change it to:

```
if (grid[i]~=nil and grid[i].blockColor) then
```